# Supporting for Larger Screen

Tags: android, screen

Currently my android application not supporting for Nexus tablet and some other tablets which i published in the android market.

i have included following support screen tag in AndroidMainfest.But it is not supporting for larger screen.Do i need to do any other thing to support for larger screen?

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"    
/>
```

Minimum SDK version is 8 and target sdk is 18.

Comment: Are there any devices you are not supporting?

Comment: No,Supporting for all devices.(Phones and Tablets)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 1 hour of searching on internet i found that by adding this tag on Manifest app supporting for most of the tablet.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

By disabling the telephony requirements application supports for more tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Create new folder in res , if you want create application for 7.9 inch tab then folder name should be layout-w768dp-land(land For landscape mode) and  for 10.1 inch layout-sw800dp-land. and put all layout(xml file inside the created folder)and after that run your application.

Comment: I tried.Not working,Still Google play developer console showing  Supported devices
4114.